# How do you permanently delete a folder inside an Azure VSTS project?

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, tfvc

I have folders within both Azures VSTS (a TFVC repository) and TFS that I needed to permanently delete. On TFS this was quite easily done using the `tf destroy $/<MyProject>/<Folder_To_Delete>` command in a command window on the server on which the TFS is running.  The web page in learn.microsoft.com that describes the "tf destroy" command (Https:// learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/destroy-command-team-foundation-version-control) shows that this command is also available for VSTS however I have been unable to get the command to work within a Developer Command Prompt window running on my local box.

`tf destroy $/<MyProject>/<Folder_To_Delete> /collection:https://<MyTeamService>.visualstudio.com/<MyProject> /login:<userid>,<password>`

The error I receive back is

***TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server:***

***Team Foundation Server Url:***

***Possible reasons for failure include:***

***- The name, port number, or protocol for the Team Foundation Server is incorrect.***

***- The Team Foundation Server is offline.***

***- The password has expired or is incorrect.***

***Technical information (for administrator):***

***The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.***

However if I put the URL into a browser my VSTS instance shows up.  So the 404 looks to me like azure is blocking outside efforts to permanently delete on VSTS. I have logged onto the Azure portal expecting to find something like the Advanced tools option you would find on Web App Services, But the Team Services / Team Projects  has nothing like this.  Can someone explain to me how to properly execute the "tf destroy" command on Azure Team Services?  Or does Azures VSTS just lack the support to permanently delete individual folders and files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tf destroy command requires a collection URL. In VSTS, there is no concept of a collection, only team projects. All team projects are created under the Default Collection.

To use the tf destroy command with VSTS, your collection URL must be in the following format:
https://**accountname**.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection

By putting a collection URL of https://**accountname**.visualstudio.com/**Project Name**, the command was looking for a collection called **Project Name** in the VSTS account, which does not exist.

This command works:
Open a Developer Command Prompt in administrator mode and issue the following command and supply your credentials.
tf destroy $/**Project Name**/**Folder To Delete** /collection:https://**accountname**.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection

Comment: Actually, the `/DefaultCollection` is redundancy, if you are using VSTS, you could just enter with `https://accountname.visualstudio.com` like my screenshot above. `tf.exe` command will auto judge this as a collection.

Answer (score 1):

To Permanently destroy an item/folder in VSTS is also using  [Destroy Command (Team Foundation Version Control)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/destroy-command-team-foundation-version-control)

```
tf destroy [/keephistory] <itemspec1>[;<versionspec>][<itemspec2>...<itemspecN>] 
[/stopat:<versionspec>] [/preview] [/startcleanup] [/noprompt] [/silent] [/login:username,[password]] [/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl]]
```

`/collection` which specifies the team project collection. However, in VSTS you only have one collection.  There is no collection name like TFS in the url. And multiple collections under user voice:

> *Let us create multiple collections on Visual Studio Team Services*
>
> https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365419/let-us-create-multiple-collections-on-visual-studi.html

So, when you specify `/collection` for VSTS in tf command line, you just need to enter `https://xxx.visualstudio.com`

Also pay attention to the  `/login:<userid>,<password>`, you are **using the wrong format**, it should be  `/login:userid,[password]`, add a `/preview` for test first(When tf destroy runs in the preview mode, the files are not actually destroyed.)

Finally the result will be

[image]

When you remove the `/preview` and perform the really destroy, you will also get a prompt info:

> Do you want to destroy $/Scrum/NugetTest/Capture1025.PNG and all of
> its children? (Yes/No/All)

Select **Yes** to delete folder and files in it, **All** with all of its children.

Comment: the second link is broken!

Comment: @RokumDev Thanks for your info, have updated, since we moved our user voice site to the new place develop community. Kindly check it.

Answer (score 0):

`https://<MyTeamService>.visualstudio.com/<MyProject>` is the wrong URL. It should just be `https://<MyTeamService>.visualstudio.com/`.

The parameter is asking for a project collection, not a team project within the collection.